# Best security practices accessing/trading crypto on computer/mobile

Tags: wallet, security, trading

I’ve read online with regards to crypto that, as hardware wallet users, we should treat all devices, computer, mobile phone, software, exchanges/wallets, etc. as compromised. That being said, I have obtained a hardware wallet and I am wanting to transfer assets on to it but i want to make sure i am always maintaining best security practices and also learning/using any new security information available. It has been sometime since I last accessed my wallet.

What is the best approach to interacting with computer, mobile phone, etc, when trading? Is it going to be a dedicated computer that is used only for crypto? And second that, is it going to be a persistent live usb drive? I am hoping to find any alternative to “get a dedicated crypto computer” possible, but if that is the single best advice I’ll do it. Barring that, what are some alternatives or other options perhaps from most ideal to least ideal for accessing/trading/reviewing crypto?

Answer (score 1):

> I’ve read online with regards to crypto that, as hardware wallet users, we should treat all devices, computer, mobile phone, software, exchanges/wallets, etc. as compromised.

Yes. This is the most important thing about Bitcoin.

- You consider software compromised, so you only go for open source solutions and stay up to date.
- You consider exchanges compromised, so you don't use them to avoid leaking privacy. You consider hardware wallet vendors compromised, so you buy them anonymously. You don't connect to untrusted web services (that is, invalid certificates and all of those things).
- You consider network compromised, so you distrust ISPs and use tools built for anonymizing communications (distrusting participants in those networks).
- You consider almost all nodes compromised, so you run your own validating full node, instead of blindly relying on others.
- You consider core compromised, so you don't keep up with latest versions all the time in all the devices/wallets.
- You consider core was compromised but not anymore, so you don't simply stay old.
- You consider bitcoin itself is compromised, so you don't act like it isn't, you don't consider it the single valid solution to all of your problems, you'll see others do so, but don't do that.

Because you fighting all of that, Bitcoin stays decentralized, and stores value.

> That being said, I have obtained a hardware wallet and I am wanting to transfer assets on to it but i want to make sure i am always maintaining best security practices and also learning/using any new security information available. It has been sometime since I last accessed my wallet.

...

> What is the best approach to interacting with computer, mobile phone, etc, when trading?

Not to in the first place. Inactive wallets perform better long term. Mobile phones are essentially the opposite of privacy.

> Is it going to be a dedicated computer that is used only for crypto?

If you can afford that, maybe. If it gets compromised, it was all for naught.

> And second that, is it going to be a persistent live usb drive?

Persistent cyphered live usb drive sounds better?

> I am hoping to find any alternative to “get a dedicated crypto computer” possible, but if that is the single best advice I’ll do it. Barring that, what are some alternatives or other options perhaps from most ideal to least ideal for accessing/trading/reviewing crypto?

Cold storage and air gapped private key access.